# Error when using checkinstall to create Python 3.12 installer on Debian 11

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, debian, checkinstall

I am using checkinstall 1.6.3 to create a .deb installer for Python 3.12 on Debian 11.

I used this description as an outline for doing it and had it working in the past for Python 3.11 on the same system:
[How to Install python3.8 using checkinstall on debian 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63314253/how-to-install-python3-8-using-checkinstall-on-debian-10)

I downloaded and unpacked the tarball from python.org, installed dependencies, and ran the following commands:

```
./configure --enable-optimizations --enable-shared --prefix=/usr
make -j $(nproc)
make -n altinstall > make_altinstall.sh
chmod +x make_altinstall.sh
sudo checkinstall -D ./make_altinstall.sh
```

checkinstall creates a lot of output, so I only include from the point where the error appears:

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/tmpklvy9437/pip-23.2.1-py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 180, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/tmp/tmpklvy9437/pip-23.2.1-py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 248, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/tmp/tmpklvy9437/pip-23.2.1-py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 324, in run
    session = self.get_default_session(options)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/tmp/tmpklvy9437/pip-23.2.1-py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 98, in get_default_session
    self._session = self.enter_context(self._build_session(options))
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/tmp/tmpklvy9437/pip-23.2.1-py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 125, in _build_session
    session = PipSession(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/tmp/tmpklvy9437/pip-23.2.1-py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 342, in __init__
    self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/tmp/tmpklvy9437/pip-23.2.1-py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 175, in user_agent
    setuptools_dist = get_default_environment().get_distribution("setuptools")
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/tmp/tmpklvy9437/pip-23.2.1-py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/metadata/importlib/_envs.py", line 188, in get_distribution
    return next(matches, None)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/tmp/tmpklvy9437/pip-23.2.1-py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/metadata/importlib/_envs.py", line 183, in <genexpr>
    matches = (
              ^
  File "/tmp/tmpklvy9437/pip-23.2.1-py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/metadata/base.py", line 612, in iter_all_distributions
    for dist in self._iter_distributions():
  File "/tmp/tmpklvy9437/pip-23.2.1-py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/metadata/importlib/_envs.py", line 176, in _iter_distributions
    for dist in finder.find_eggs(location):
  File "/tmp/tmpklvy9437/pip-23.2.1-py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/metadata/importlib/_envs.py", line 144, in find_eggs
    yield from self._find_eggs_in_dir(location)
  File "/tmp/tmpklvy9437/pip-23.2.1-py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/metadata/importlib/_envs.py", line 115, in _find_eggs_in_dir
    with os.scandir(location) as it:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "/home/thomas/Downloads/Python-3.12.0/Lib/ensurepip/__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(ensurepip._main())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/thomas/Downloads/Python-3.12.0/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 284, in _main
    return _bootstrap(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/thomas/Downloads/Python-3.12.0/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 200, in _bootstrap
    return _run_pip([*args, *_PACKAGE_NAMES], additional_paths)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/thomas/Downloads/Python-3.12.0/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 101, in _run_pip
    return subprocess.run(cmd, check=True).returncode
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/thomas/Downloads/Python-3.12.0/Lib/subprocess.py", line 571, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/home/thomas/Downloads/Python-3.12.0/python', '-W', 'ignore::DeprecationWarning', '-c', '\nimport runpy\nimport sys\nsys.path = [\'/tmp/tmpklvy9437/pip-23.2.1-py3-none-any.whl\'] + sys.path\nsys.argv[1:] = [\'install\', \'--no-cache-dir\', \'--no-index\', \'--find-links\', \'/tmp/tmpklvy9437\', \'--root\', \'/\', \'--upgrade\', \'pip\']\nrunpy.run_module("pip", run_name="__main__", alter_sys=True)\n']' returned non-zero exit status 2.

****  Installation failed. Aborting package creation.

Cleaning up...OK

Bye.
```

It seems like the error may have something to do with pip or setuptools. Any tips on how to fix this issue are much appreciated.